# Elasticsearch term_statistics/doc_freq always returns 1

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I’ve recently started using Elasticsearch via the Python API, and am trying to get the frequency of each word across a set of documents using term vectors.

I’m using multiple the Multi termvectors API as follows:

```
    results = es.mtermvectors(index=INDEX_NAME, doc_type=DOC_TYPE, ids="1,2",
                              fields=['text'],
                              field_statistics=True,
                              term_statistics=True)
```

However, this returns a separate set of results for each doc, whereas I'm trying to get total results across all docs. The term_statistics/doc_freq value (“the number of documents containing the current term”) should give me the info I need, but this is always 1 as separate results are returned for each doc. Any ideas how I can get doc_freq to return meaningful values? Do I need to use aggregation?

Relevant docs here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-termvectors.html
http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Could you see the sum_ttf field - total term frequency - in your output? In the output in the doc that you have posted it appears https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html

Comment: doc_count indicates the frequency of that word for that specific doc, in your case you call 2 docs: 1 with id 1 and another one with id 2

Comment: Hi Lupanoide – thanks for getting back to me. I’ve edited my question to refer to term_statistics/doc_freq as this is the value returned for each term, though the problem is still the same (value is always 1).
As an example, the word “or” appears in both documents. The term_vectors results for “or” in document 1 are:  
    `doc_freq = 1,  
    ttf = 2`.

The term_vectors results for “or” in document 2 are:  
`doc_freq = 1`,  
`ttf = 1`.

The documentation states “document frequency (the number of documents containing the current term)”, so I expect the value of doc_freq to be 2.